# unable to collect Stateflow in Lifecycle aware manner in onCreate function of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, stateflow

unable to collect Stateflow in Lifecycle  aware manner  in onCreate function of a fragment

I have a stateflow which is collected from the viewmodel

```
private val _someFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<Students>>(emptyList())

val getSomeFlow = _someFlow.stateIn(initialValue = emptyList(),
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000)
)

init {
    getAllStudents()
}

fun getAllStudents() = viewModelScope.launch {
    studentRepository.getAllStudents()
        .catch { e ->
            Log.d(
                "main",
                "Exception: ${e.message} "
            )
        }.collect {
            _someFlow.value = it
        }
}
```

I am trying to collect it in the fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(
    view: View,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) {
    super.onViewCreated(
        view,
        savedInstanceState
    )

viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        launch {
            studentViewModel.getSomeFlow.filter { data ->
                data.isNotEmpty()
            }.collectLatest { data -> studentList = data }
        }
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {

        for (student in studentList) {

        }
    }
}
```

How ever the list is not populated

when we use `lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED)`

it works , but in most of the examples it is mentioned to use `Lifecycle.State.CREATED`

so the question is what should we use the collect the stateflow in proper lifecycle aware manner